# Telephone number format in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I need to format telephone number from **787877878** to **78 787 78 78**, 
can anybody tel me how to create **filter** for this?

Answer (score 1):

**Filter**

You can use this little snippet of code if you modify it for your needs, it uses a regex, `slice` and a switch.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hd_deman/4UcNC/)